# fatal: Not a git repository ... error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push

When I git push on heroku, I receive this 
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` error many times. Everything works fine in my application and the push completes normally. I just wonder why this happens.
I also see the same message 4-5 times in my logs in heroku, when a scheduler task runs.
Any idea? Thanks!

```
git push staging master

Counting objects: 41, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 1.74 KiB, done.
Total 21 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
      Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
      Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
      Using rake (10.0.3)
      Using i18n (0.6.1)
      Using multi_json (1.5.0)
      Using builder (3.0.4)
      Using erubis (2.7.0)
      Using journey (1.0.4)
      Using rack-cache (1.2)
      Using rack-test (0.6.2)
      Using jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      Using backbone-on-rails (0.9.2.1)
      Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
      Using sass (3.2.1)
      Using cancan (1.6.7)
      Using carrierwave (0.6.2) from git://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave.git (at master)
      Using chosen-rails (0.9.8)
      Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      Using commonjs (0.2.6)
      Using orm_adapter (0.3.0)
          .......

      Using warden (1.2.1)
      Using devise (2.1.2)
      Using nokogiri (1.5.4)
      Using ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
      Using fog (1.3.1)
      Using gmaps4rails (1.5.5)
      Using jquery-datatables-rails (1.10.0)
      Using jquery-fileupload-rails (0.3.4)
      Using jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2)
      Using less (2.2.2)
      Using less-rails (2.2.6)
      Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.5)
      Using rails (3.2.11)
      Using newrelic_rpm (3.5.3.25)
      Using paper_trail (2.6.3)
      Using pg (0.13.2)
      Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
      Using simple_form (2.0.2)
      Using squeel (1.0.11)
      Using strong_parameters (0.1.5)
      Using therubyracer (0.10.2)
      Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.9)
      Using uglifier (1.2.5)
      Using validate_email (0.1.5)
      Using validate_url (0.2.0)
      Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
      Cleaning up the bundler cache.
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
      Running: rake assets:precompile
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      Asset precompilation completed (274.30s)
-----> Rails plugin injection
      Injecting rails_log_stdout
      Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
      Procfile declares types      -> (none)
      Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size: 31.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v22
      http://***************-staging.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `git init` in your project to initialize a git repository. You can see heroku configuration in the following link [git remote doesn't seem to be working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755529/git-remote-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-at-all).

Comment: I already have a local repo and many commits already (stored in github also), before I push to remote repo of heroku.

Comment: Do you use gemspeck? It seems that it may cause the problem you have as you can see in https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/3

Comment: Thanks William, I had seen this notice from hone, but I dont use `gemspec` and I didn't find any `gemspec` auto generated file. It must be something else.

Comment: It seems that there are oher gem that have the same problem of gemspec. Try to remove the gems to verify which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is really really late but you should try this:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

run that in the console and then update your repo.  Then push to github... Then push to heroku.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the assets locally then push to heroku worked for me.

This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22975650/7693